# Can I edit those fields values via pyvmomi

Tags: vmware, pyvmomi

I'm struggeling to get my head around Vmware's MOB.

I have found the page in MOB which has got the coresponding fields I'm interested in i.e. DRS and HA setting for a cluster.

However I'm not sure if I can edit them via **pyvmomi** since the page in the MOB doesn't have any method table below the properties table.

This is what I mean:

**My page:**

[image]

**Some other page:**

[image]

**Is it possible to edit DRS and HA properies via pyvmomi or the only thing I can do with pyvmomi is just to "fetch" them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `ReconfigureCluster_Task` method of the [`ClusterComputeResource`](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#https%3A%2F%2Fvdc-repo.vmware.com%2Fvmwb-repository%2Fdcr-public%2F6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22%2Ffa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc%2Fdoc%2Fvim.ClusterComputeResource.html). Look at the `dasConfig` and `drsConfig` fields of the [`ClusterConfigSpecEx`](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#https%3A%2F%2Fvdc-repo.vmware.com%2Fvmwb-repository%2Fdcr-public%2F6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22%2Ffa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc%2Fdoc%2Fvim.cluster.ConfigSpecEx.html).

These seem to be accessible through `pyvmomi` as per the example [here](https://github.com/rreubenur/vmware-pyvmomi-examples/blob/master/disable_HA_on_particular_VM.py).

Comment: Thanks that's is what I was looking for. On the side note do you know why `vim.cluster.DasConfigInfo` says `hostMonitoring = <unset>` and **MOB** shows it as `hostMonitoring "enabled"`.

Comment: If the MOB shows it as `enabled`, where do you see it as unset? In `pyvmomi`?

Comment: Thank you for getting back @YSK. Almost every single value which has been "configured" in **MOB** is being displayed as `<unset>` by **pyvmomi** (look at my `print()` functions), This is what I'm running https://gist.github.com/MichalTaratuta/92e419d2dd8be7eebc3bf9af8078ab7d  I'm just starting with pyvmomi so I'm not sure if it's me not "calling" something correctly or something else.

Comment: I don't know pyvmomi all that well... Do you actually get it to show you all the fields that are e.g. in `DasConfigInfo`? What happens if you print out one specific field - for example `cluster.DasVmConfigInfo.Priority.disabled`?